# how do i get data from all the states and dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I tried to get the info from json for a particular state and district but how do I get all the info from all states and districts?

Here is my code:

```
def district_data_andhra(today):
    data = requests.get(url='https://api.covid19india.org/districts_daily.json').json()
    # print(data)
    # print(type(data['districtsDaily']))
    for k,v in data['districtsDaily'].items():
        for i in v.items():
            print(i[0])
            print(i[1])


    data = data['districtsDaily']['Andhra Pradesh']['West Godavari']
    today_andhra_data = {}
    # print(data)
    for obj in data:
        if str(today) == obj['date']:
            today_andhra_data['deceased'] = obj['deceased']
            today_andhra_data['recovered'] = obj['recovered']
            today_andhra_data['confirmed'] = obj['confirmed']
            today_andhra_data['active'] = obj['active']
```

Comment: You should look the json module. It might help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you asked, but if you want to get information, from all districts, in sequence, you can do this:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.covid19india.org/districts_daily.json').json()
for state, districts in r['districtsDaily'].items():
    print('State:', state)
    for district_info in districts.items():
        print('District:', district_info[0])
        for status in district_info[1]:
            print(status['date'])
            print('Confirmed:', status['confirmed'])
            print('Active:', status['active'])
            print('Deceased:', status['deceased'])
            print('Recovered:', status['recovered'])
```